# Python and BeautifulSoup encoding issue from UTF-8

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python and currently writing an application that scrapes data off the web. It's mostly done, there is only a little problem left with encoding. The site is encoded in `ISO-8859-1`, but when I try to `html.decode('iso-8859-1')`, it doesn't do anything.
If you run the program, use `50000` and `50126` for PLZs and you'll see what I mean in the output. It would be awesome if someone could help me out.

```
import urllib.request
import time
import csv
import operator

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#Performs a HTTP-'POST' request, passes it to BeautifulSoup and returns the result
def doRequest(request):
    requestResult = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requestResult)
    return soup


#Returns all the result links from the given search parameters
def getLinksFromSearch(plz_von, plz_bis):
    database = []
    links = []

    #The search parameters
    params = {
    'name_ff': '',
    'strasse_ff': '',
    'plz_ff': plz_von,
    'plz_ff2': plz_bis,
    'ort_ff': '',
    'bundesland_ff': '',
    'land_ff': 'DE',
    'traeger_ff': '',
    'Dachverband_ff': '',
    'submit2' : 'Suchen'
    }

    DATA = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
    DATA = DATA.encode('utf-8')

    request = urllib.request.Request(
    "http://www.altenheim-adressen.de/schnellsuche/suche1.cfm",
    DATA)

    # adding charset parameter to the Content-Type header.
    request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8")
    request.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0")

    #The search request 
    html = doRequest(request)
    h = html.decode('iso-8859-1')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(h)

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        database.append(link.get('href'))

    #Remove the first Element ('None') to avoid Attribute Errors
    database.pop(0)

    for item in database:
        if item.startswith("suche"):
            links.append(item)

    return links



#Performs a search on the link results
def searchOnLinks(links):
    adresses = []
    i = 1
    j = len(links)
    print("Found", j, "results, collecting data.")
    for item in links:
        adresses.append(getContactInfoFromPage(item, i, j))
        i = i + 1
        time.sleep(0.1)
    print("All done.")
    return adresses

#A method to scrape the contact info from the search result
def getContactInfoFromPage(page, i, j):
    name = ''
    straße = ''
    plz = ''
    stadt = ''
    telefon = ''
    mail = ''
    url = ''

    data = [
           #'Name',
           #'Straße',
           #'PLZ',
           #'Stadt',
           #'Telefon',
           #'E-Mail',
           #'Homepage'
            ]

    request = urllib.request.Request("http://www.altenheim-adressen.de/schnellsuche/" + page)
    #request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8")
    request.add_header("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8")
    request.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0")


    print("(" , i , "/" , j , ") Making request...") 
    soup = doRequest(request)
    print("Done.")

    findeName = soup.findAll('b')
    name = findeName[2]
    name = name.string.split('>')

    data.append(name[0])

    straße = getFieldValue(soup, "Straße")
    data.append(straße)

    ort = getFieldValue(soup, "Ort")
    (plz, stadt) = ort.split(' ', 1)
    data.append(plz)
    data.append(stadt)

    telefon = getFieldValue(soup, "Telefon")
    data.append(telefon)

    mail = getFieldValue(soup, "EMail")
    data.append(mail)

    url = getFieldValue(soup, "Internetadresse")
    data.append(url)

    return data

#Strips the text from the given field's sibling
def getFieldValue(soup, field):
    field_label = soup.find('td', text=field + ':')
    return field_label.find_next_sibling('td').get_text(strip=True)

#The main input/output function
def inputOutput():
    #PLZ is German for zip-code and consists of a five-digit number
    #The program passes the numbers to the servers, and the server
    #returns all search results between the two numbers
    plz_von = input("Please enter first PLZ: ")
    plz_bis = input("Please enter second PLZ: ")

    links = getLinksFromSearch(plz_von, plz_bis)

    #Checks if the search yielded any results
    if len(links) > 0:
        data = searchOnLinks(links)
        file_name = input("Save as: ")
        print("Writing to file...")
        with open(file_name + '.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
            a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
            a.writerows(data)

    else:
        print("The search yielded no results.")


inputOutput()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `doRequest()` function returns a *BeautifulSoup object*, you cannot decode that object. Just use it directly:

```
soup = doRequest(request)
```

You don't need to decode the response at all; BeautifulSoup uses both hints in the HTML (`<meta>` headers) as well as statistical analysis to determine the correct input encoding.

In this case the HTML document claims it is Latin-1:

```html
<meta name="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

The response doesn't include a character set in the Content-Type header either, so this is a case of a misconfigured server. You can force BeautifulSoup to ignore the `<meta>` header with:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requestResult, from_encoding='utf8')
```

Comment: Thanks, but that returns a NoneType-Error, probably because it was already decoded by BeautifulSoup in the `doRequest(request)`-method. When I decode it your way, it throws an AttributeError on the second request. Things are getting weird. EDIT: Nevermind, I found it.

Comment: Hm, still produces `Ã¤` instead of `ä`.

Comment: @FreshPrince: in the *CSV output*? Are you certain you are opening that file correctly? `Ã¤` means you are reading the file using a Windows codepage instead of using UTF-8.

Comment: It also shows me `Ã¤` when I open it with gedit and other text editors, and when I print out the data to the console before saving it, so my guess is that BeautifulSoup probably has problems with decoding the page.

Comment: @FreshPrince: re-open the file as UTF-8; BeautifulSoup is handling the unicode response just fine.

Comment: @FreshPrince: ah, the *original data* has that error! The HTML contains `<meta name="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`, so BeautifulSoup correctly decodes it. But the response contains both Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) *and* UTF-8 data in the response. The **server** creates a [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). In the browser this doesn't appear to happen, perhaps your Content-Type header causes this.

Comment: @FreshPrince: no, the server produces that output regardless. I don't yet know why it works in a browser.

Comment: @FreshPrince: ah, my browser overrides the meta header; it notices something is wrong and auto-detects UTF-8.

Comment: @FreshPrince: the response is all UTF-8, but it is lying about the characterset. You can override this (force BeautifulSoup to use UTF-8), I'll update.